# Disabling zoom-in zoom-out functionality of the UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am new to iOS development and I am developing an application which will show and web page in `UIWebView`. I want to get rid of the default `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` functionality of the `webview`.

Comment: Please consider to check one of the answers as the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

This is in the Apple Documentation:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL scalesPageToFit
Discussion
If YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.
```

**Interface Builder Approach:**

1. Make sure that the "Scale pages to fit" tick box in the right-side column of the interface builder when you click on your webview is un-ticked. It's right at the top.
2. You're also going to need to un-tick the box that says "Multiple Touch" around half way down. That will disable pinching to zoom.

**Code Approach:**

You can also do it programmatically with this code:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

You're also going to want to add:

```
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

That will disable the ability to pinch and zoom, since it disables the ability to use multiple fingers in an action, and pinching requires two, obviously!

Comment: webView.multipleTouchEnabled does nothing to the webview.

Answer (score 6):

set the UIWebView property scalesPageToFit to NO, will disable the user zooming

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

Answer (score 5):

One simply needs to do:

`myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;`

and also disable the pesky pinch to zoom:

`webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;`

Comment: webView.multipleTouchEnabled does nothing to the webview.

Answer (score 3):

For me the ideal solution was, surprinsingly, in the html side only. Just add this in `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0" />
```

I don't recommend to use `webView.scalesPageToFit = false` because it brings issues like making everything 4x bigger. I also did not use `initial-scale=1.0`, `maximum-scale=1.0` nor `minmum-scale=1.0`

Answer (score 2):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollView.delegate = self;//self must be UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return nil;
}
```

try this ... It works..

Answer (score 2):

Disable bouncesZoom of the scrollView will solve your problem. Give it a try!

```
webView.scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
```

Answer (score 1):

When inheriting from UIWebView you can implement. (Works from iOS 5, lower not sure)

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Solution**

Simply set the value mentioned above to false: `webView.scalesPageToFit = false`

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers, this will work:

```
webView.scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also struggle at first when i use webview scroll event after that i fond the below code for disable the scroll in webview and this also remove the multitouch gestures function in that particular webview.

> [[[theWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];

here theWebView is the name of my UIWebView..
use this code in webViewDidFinishLoad function ,,, its really helpful to me,..